# lost packet in ntp server. How to solve? Select is not working

Tags: c, sockets

For some reason I do not know sometimes my device does not receive an answer from ntp server and got stuck in the read socket. I try to solve this using a select. But I am always getting timeout. What is wrong with the use of select? It always return 0 instead of the number of bytes

int ntp_get_time(char *host_name) {

```
int sockfd, n; // Socket file descriptor and the n return result from writing/reading from the socket.

int portno = 123; // NTP UDP port number.
// Structure that defines the 48 byte NTP packet protocol.


// Create and zero out the packet. All 48 bytes worth.

ntp_packet packet = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

memset(&packet, 0, sizeof(ntp_packet));

// Set the first byte's bits to 00,011,011 for li = 0, vn = 3, and mode = 3. The rest will be left set to zero.

*((char *) &packet + 0) = 0x1b; // Represents 27 in base 10 or 00011011 in base 2.

// Create a UDP socket, convert the host-name to an IP address, set the port number,
// connect to the server, send the packet, and then read in the return packet.

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; // Server address data structure.
struct hostent *server;      // Server data structure.

sockfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP); // Create a UDP socket.

if (sockfd < 0) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "ERROR opening socket");
    if (sockfd)
        close(sockfd); // [joao]
    return -1;
}
dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "host_name: %s", host_name);
server = gethostbyname(host_name); // Convert URL to IP.

if (server == NULL) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "ERROR, no such host");
    if (sockfd)
        close(sockfd); // [joao]
    return -1;
}

// Zero out the server address structure.

bzero((char*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

// Copy the server's IP address to the server address structure.

bcopy((char*) server->h_addr, ( char* ) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length );

// Convert the port number integer to network big-endian style and save it to the server address structure.

serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

// Call up the server using its IP address and port number.

if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))
        < 0) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "ERROR connecting");
    if (sockfd)
        close(sockfd); // [joao]
    return -1;
}
else {
    dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "conect sockect success");
}

struct timeval t0;
int res = 0;
res = gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "gettimeofday res = %d", res);

// Send it the NTP packet it wants. If n == -1, it failed.
n = write(sockfd, (char*) &packet, sizeof(ntp_packet));

if (n < 0) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "ERROR writing to socket");
    if (sockfd)
        close(sockfd); // [joao]
    return -1;
}
else {
    dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "write sockect success");
}

// Wait and receive the packet back from the server. If n == -1, it failed.
fd_set rfds;
struct timeval timeout;
int retval;
/* Watch stdin (fd 0) to see when it has input. */
FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(sockfd, &rfds);
/* Wait up to five seconds. */
timeout.tv_sec = 2;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

retval = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
/* Don't rely on the value of tv now! */

if (retval == -1) {
     dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "error in select =%d", retval);
    return retval;
}
else if (retval) {
    n = read(sockfd, (char*) &packet, sizeof(ntp_packet));
    dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "read sockfd n =%d", n);
}
else {
    dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "No data within 2 seconds retval =%d", retval);
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: This code is not working

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information istead of writing comments. The problem description "is not working" is too general. What exactly is not working? What does your code do, what happens and what would you expect to happen. If your program prints some output, copy&paste it to the question. How did you check that the result of `select` is wrong?